# Can't get cookies to save in form using JavaScript. New to Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hi I am new to JavaScript and am working on a project. I am trying to get cookies to save when I submit my form, go back a page, and then refresh. I can get it to save the cookie in Firefox and Edge but not chrome. Would anybody be able to tell me what I am missing?

Javacript:

```
"use strict";

function processCookie(){
if(document.getElementById("rememberInput").checked){
    document.cookie = "username=" + document.getElementById("usernameinput").value;

}else{
    var expiresDate = new Date();
    expiresDate.setDate(expiresDate.getDate - 7);
    document.cookie = "username=null; expires" + expiresDate.toUTCString();

}


}

function populateInfo(){
    if(document.cookie){
        var uname = document.cookie;
        uname = uname.substring(uname.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
        document.getElementById("usernameinput").value = uname;

    }

}

function handleSubmit(var evt ){
    if(evt.preventDefault){
        evt.preventDefault();
    }else{
        evt.returnValue = false;
    }
    processCookie();
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}

function createEventListener(){
    var loginForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    if(loginForm.addEventListener){
        loginForm.addEventListener("submit",handleSubmit,false);
    }else if(loginForm.attachEvent){
        loginForm.attachEvent("onsubmit",handleSubmit,false);
    }

}

function setUpPage(){
    populateInfo();
    createEventListener();

}

if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener("load",setUpPage,false);

}else if(window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent("onload",setUpPage);

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta id="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0">
<title>Hands-on Project 9-2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="modernizr.custom.65897.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1>
        Hands-on Project 9-3
    </h1>
</header>

<article>
    <div id="errorMessage"></div>
    <form action="results.htm">
        <fieldset id="deliveryinfo">
            <legend>Site Login</legend>
            <label for="usernameinput">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="usernameinput" name="username" />
            <label for="passwordinput">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="passwordinput" name="password" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberinput" name="remember" value="remember" />
            <label for="rememberinput" id="rememberlabel">Remember me</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="submitbutton">
            <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</article>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Use localStorage for that. cookies are hell.

Comment: @JonasW. localStorage is way better. But if you must use cookies. Have you checked to make sure cookies were enabled in Chrome?

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help. Unfortunately, this is for a class so some of these awesome suggestions will not work. I am afraid my problem may be that Chrome just doesn't want to play with my local cookies since ie and Firefox are both behaving. I am not sure if that is a thing but as of right now I accept it. I will save these suggestions for later use when I am not constrained by the man.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this library [js cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) this will help you to manage cookies in an easy way

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
Cookies.get('name');
```